# create account produces "is nodeos running?" error

Tags: cleos, account-creation

I need a way to restart my development environment fresh so I have a little script like this:

```
    quit 'keosd'
    quit 'nodeos'
    rm -rf eosio
    rm -rf ~/eosio-wallet
    nohup keosd > keosd.log 2>&1 &
    nohup node > nodeos.log 2>&1 &
    cleos wallet create --file .Wallet
    cleos create key --file .Key
    PK=5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3
    cleos wallet import --private-key=$PK
    PK=$(head -1 .Key |sed 's/Private key: //')
    cleos wallet import --private-key=$PK
    PK=$(tail -1 .Key |sed 's/Public key: //')
    cmd="cleos create account eosio t $PK $PK"
    echo $cmd
    $cmd
```

but when the script gets to the last line I get the dreaded error:

> Failed to connect to nodeos at http://127.0.0.1:8888/; is nodeos running?

though if I run `cleos get info` I can see nodeos is running and curiously, if I run the command by hand (shown below as printed by the script), it works.  but the call from the script fails

> cleos create account eosio t EOS7Yo3xXD35Ct3Bu9BnwGDR5cUZDscwUtu9Kxc9ywJyJSuUFn2fL EOS7Yo3xXD35Ct3Bu9BnwGDR5cUZDscwUtu9Kxc9ywJyJSuUFn2fL

for completeness:

```
quit() {
    s=$(echo $1 |sed 's/./[&]/') # this trick prevents grep from finding itself
    id=$(ps aux |grep $s |awk '{print $2}')
    [ ! -z $id ] && kill $id
}
node() {
    nodeos -e -p eosio \
        --plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
        --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
        --plugin eosio::http_plugin \
        --plugin eosio::history_plugin \
        --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
        --data-dir /Users/ekkis/dev/eos/eosio/data \
        --config-dir /Users/ekkis/dev/eos/eosio/config \
        --access-control-allow-origin='*' \
        --contracts-console \
        --http-validate-host=false \
        --verbose-http-errors \
        --delete-all-blocks \
        --filter-on='*'
}
```

and I'm running on OSX 10.14 (Mojave) with CDT v1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# wait for nodeos
until curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info
do
  sleep 1s
done
```

Answer (score 0):

ok... the problem seems to be that when the account creation command runs, the node hasn't yet come up.  the reason the wallet imports run is that those commands go to `keosd` instead, which comes up much more quickly

so the answer is to `sleep 1` or some suitable period before trying to talk to the daemon